# C backtracking Sudoku solver

Tags: algorithm, c, sudoku, backtracking

I wrote this program in C to solve a given Sudoku puzzle (represented as 2D array) using backtracking algorithm. How can I make it more efficient, maybe faster and more C-onic?

This is my first post here, all suggestions are welcome! (be pedantic with me!)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GRID_SIZE 9

typedef int (*grid)[GRID_SIZE];
typedef struct { int x, y; } v2;

void dump(const grid board)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; ++j)
            printf("%d ", board[i][j]);
        puts("");
    }
}

int possible(const grid board, const v2 pos, const int v)
{
    int i, j, x0, y0;

    for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i)
        if (board[pos.y][i] == v)
            return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i)
        if (board[i][pos.x] == v)
            return 0;

    x0 = (pos.x / 3) * 3;
    y0 = (pos.y / 3) * 3;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            if (board[i + y0][j + x0] == v)
                return 0;

    return 1;
}

void solve(grid board)
{
    int y, x, v;

    for (y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; ++y)
        for (x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; ++x)
            if (board[y][x] == 0)
            {
                for (v = 1; v < 10; ++v)
                {
                    const v2 pos = {x, y};
                    if (possible(board, pos, v))
                    {
                        board[y][x] = v;
                        solve(board);
                        board[y][x] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }

    dump(board);
}

int main(void)
{
    /* 0 represents an empty cell */
    int board[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] =
    {
        {7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3},
        {0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0},
        {0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 5},
        {0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 7, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 0},
        {3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0},
        {0, 0, 8, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0},
        {5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9},
    };

    solve(board);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This look great, to me. How can it be more efficient? Sudoku solving is a well studied area, one observation is that you can implement 'Algorithm X' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X which applies to Sudoku https://rafal.io/posts/solving-sudoku-with-dancing-links.html and this will be faster on average. I imagine though that there are faster more bespoke algorithms you could find and implement. Personally I think the nicest thing to do is not any faster, which is to rephrase Sudokus as extending a graph colouring, and instead write an algorithm which extends graph colourings.

Comment: There seems to be a key problem with the code.  1) the `board` is declared as a 2 dimensional array of `int`s  2) the `grid` is defined as a single array of 9 pointers to `int`.  Therefore, IMO: there is a serious problem with the code logic

Comment: @user3629249 `grid` is a pointer to an array of `GRID_SIZE` integers. notice the parentheses. a pointer to an array is a 2d array.

Answer (score 2):

I would tag your `struct` in addition to, if not instead of, using a `typedef`:

```
struct v2
{
    int x, y;
};
// typedef struct v2 v2;
```

Then you can use `struct v2` wherever you are using `v2`. This makes it clear that `v2` is a structure.

I think you should create a symbolic `SUBGRID_SIZE` instead of using `3` here:

```
x0 = (pos.x / 3) * 3;
y0 = (pos.y / 3) * 3;

for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        if (board[i + y0][j + x0] == v)
            return 0;
```

This would make it more obvious about what you're dealing with. I would put `GRID_SIZE` and `SUBGRID_SIZE` next to each other, and then use an `#if` to check if they're valid:

```
#define GRID_SIZE 9
#define SUBGRID_SIZE 3

#if SUBGRID_SIZE * SUBGRID_SIZE != GRID_SIZE
# error grid size and subgrid size dont match
#endif
```

You might use `printf("\n");` or `putchar('\n');` instead of `puts("");`. The compiler is likely to optimize the former into `puts("");` anyway, and the second may be faster.

I like that you've used `const` everywhere that you're not going to modify a variable. This eliminates chances to make mistakes.

Your formatting is very good. It is consistent, too.

Your code is also well-commented. The only thing that was slightly non-obvious you've commented:

```
/* 0 represents an empty cell */
```

Being pedantic with you, your code has zero warnings with `-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic`.

Comment: Thank you for you comment! and, I better `#define` `SUBGRID_SIZE` as sqrt(GRID_SIZE), don't I? then I don't have to change 2 constants, just one.
("It is set on a board with NxN squares where N is a number with a whole-number square root (4x4, 9x9, etc.)")

Comment: @Shechner I have a better solution where `SUBGRID_SIZE` is a constant; see my edit.

Comment: I like it, but don't you think sqrting is better since it is dynamic?

Comment: @Shechner `sqrt` gives a `double` result which will cause a conversion to `double` on every iteration. `double` conversion takes time, and a decent amount of it, too. A static constant will almost always be faster, and will leave even less room for errors if you have that `#if` there. For example, if `GRID_SIZE` is `10` and `SUBGRID_SIZE` is `sqrt(GRID_SIZE)` vs. `GRID_SIZE` is `10` and `SUBGRID_SIZE` is `3`; the error in the latter will be caught but the error in the former will not.